# How to concatenate files in sorted order?

Tags: bash

I have a directory of files and I want to merge them. The only problem is that I want to merge them in the exactly same order that they appear by calling "`ls -l`".

Comment: Glob expansions are all sorted (per `LC_COLLATE` configuration) already. What do you expect `ls` to be adding to that?

Comment: BTW, for cases like sorting by time, the solutions get more interesting. See BashFAQ #3: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shell already sorts globs, out-of-the-box. Thus, for either:

```
# works only if the number of names is short enough to fit in one invocation
cat * >../output.txt
```

...or, its cousin with support for more names than will fit on a single command line...

```
# works for any arbitrary number of names
printf '%s\0' * | xargs -0 cat >../output.txt
```

...output is already sorted according to the collation order defined in `LC_COLLATE` (a variable which `ls` is also supposed to honor in any sorting it may perform).

Comment: Makes me want an `ls -0` feature.

Comment: @Myria, indeed -- POSIX support for `-0` / `-z` (across the board -- so `sort`, `comm`, and all your other standard tools as well) would be a beautiful thing; I hope that someday the proposals actually make it into the standard. For that matter, it'd also be nice to have `read -0` guaranteed, rather than needing the unwieldy `IFS= read -r -d ''` incantation.

Comment: Your 2nd example still has to fit all the filenames in one invocation of printf. Doesn't it suffer the same risks as the 1st?

Comment: @glennjackman, no, because `printf` is a builtin. There's no `execv`, thus no `ARG_MAX` limit..

Answer (score 1):

```
cat `ls` > ../output.txt
```

output.txt must be in a different directory, or else the `cat` will fail.

Example run:

```
[myria@machine dir]$ echo Kitty > Kitty.txt
[myria@machine dir]$ echo Meow > Meow.txt
[myria@machine dir]$ echo Cat > Cat.txt
[myria@machine dir]$ echo Purr > Purr.txt
[myria@machine dir]$ cat `ls` > ../output.txt
[myria@machine dir]$ cat ../output.txt
Cat
Kitty
Meow
Purr
```

This may fail if the number of files is large.  There are better solutions for esoteric cases, like noted in the comments.

Comment: This won't work with all possible filenames. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Even with the edit -- no, `ls | xargs cat` does not work with all possible names -- look at names with spaces in them, for a very easy example of where it's broken.

Comment: ...for a trickier one, try creating a file like so: `echo "content" >$'foo\nbar'`.